# Android cannot find symbol variable error for spinner

Tags: android

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/activity_time_spinner"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

There is my spinner item in my Layout file as it is shown above. 
So when I declare my spinner in my Activity class as it is shown below:

```
activity_time_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.activity_time_spinner);
```

I got an error. The error is: "**Error:(196, 60) error: cannot find symbol variable activity_time_spinner**".

My R class is imported like "**import com.example.myapp.R;**"

Why I got the error ?

Comment: share your complete code.

Comment: try build->clean cache. If that doesn't work do File->Invalidate Caches.

Comment: Try to `clean- ReBuild` your project

Comment: None of those answers worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you didn't set the correct layout file in your Activity, make sure the XML layout file you are using is the one you think you are, and that you are setting it correctly.

Something like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

We can't tell with the limited amount of information you shared.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import "android.R". That should be auto generated.

Below are some steps if it is still appear:

- Clean your build, then rebuild
- Perform a Gradle sync (via Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files)

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler is complaining that your Java variable `activity_time_spinner` isn't defined.

Instead of this:

```
activity_time_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.activity_time_spinner);
```

try this instead:

```
Spinner activity_time_spinner = findViewById(R.id.activity_time_spinner);
```

Stylistically, it looks a little better to use camelCase for Android Java code but that's more of a preference thing:

```
Spinner activityTimeSpinner = findViewById(R.id.activity_time_spinner);
```